# How compile PHP modules/extensions from source

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, redis, php-fastcgi

I have set-up multiple PHP versions on single apache ubuntu instance using below tutorial.

> https://gist.github.com/jbinfo/d297fcfdb151e25a299c

Both PHP versions working fine but php-geoip and php-redis extensions are missing.

> How can I compile both extensions from source.

Is there any way to enable PHP extensions and modules from source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compile php-redis following these [steps](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis#installation) and for GeoIP you can follow these [steps](http://php.net/manual/en/geoip.setup.php#93000) and as a general rule each compilation process should generate a `*.so` file which you should move it to the extensions directory then enable it in `php.ini` for example `extension="redis.so"` this will make php.ini load the `.so` file from the extension dir that is configured for your php version. (sometimes `make install` will do that for you when you compile an extension)

Please note that [php-redis](http://pecl.php.net/package/redis), [geoip](http://pecl.php.net/package/geoip) is available through pecl in case you don't want to compile them

Comment: I'm using PHP 5.5 and 5.6. Is there any versions compatibility

Comment: download the source code that is compatible with your version from pecl then compile it or use pecl to install them without compilation